# Why does AMFPHP store integers as two bytes for the AMF protocol?

Tags: php, integer, amfphp

I'm wondering if anyone familiar with AMFPHP or low level data storage could explain why integers are being stored as two bytes instead of four.  As far as I can tell, the AMF3 protocol demands a four byte integer.  The specific code in the serializer is the following:

```
/**
 * writeInt takes an int and writes it as 2 bytes to the output stream
 * 0-65535 range
 * 
 * @param int $n An integer to convert to a 2 byte binary string
 */
function writeInt($n) {
    $this->outBuffer .= pack("n", $n); // use pack with the n flag
}
```

I realize this question may be too specific, but can anyone help answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for a quite nice explanation how it works:
[AMF message structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499205/amf-message-structure/1557312#1557312)