# Deserialising AMF via Proxy

Tags: java, serialization, proxy, blazeds, amf

I want to deserialize an Onlinegame AMF Stream to create various overviews (Items in stock, numbers of buildings, type of buildings etc.)

To do this i implemented an Proxy in Java. My Firefox connects to the proxy perfectly and this proxy works fine too.

But i'm not able to analyse the AMF Stream.

Here is my source: http://pastebin.com/ex8EkEZU
an example of one of these requests: http://pastebin.com/y7GzqwDy

Does anyone got an idea or tutorial? thnx.

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out the AMF requests to look at them?  You can use a tool like ServiceCapture, or Charles, or the Flash Builder Network Monitor.  However, I feel it is bad Karma to use such tools to try to use this to reverse engineer someone elses app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AMF message structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499205/amf-message-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [amf-serializer](http://code.google.com/p/amf-serializer/) or the [Java AMF Client](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client) from BlazeDS? Both of these should handle deserialization of AMF0/3